# Unset (remove) a field (views_conditional will not work)

Tags: views, 8

I have a view that produces a table. 
In addition to the fields defined in the source nodes, I've added a link to "edit the node" via the Views admin UI.

Obviously, this link should not be visible, or better yet, not rendered at all unless the user has privilege. So - based on some business logic, I want to suppress  the "Edit the Node" link at runtime depending on (in this case) whether the user has edit privileges.

A similar question here was answered with a recommendation to use https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional

This will is not a very viable alternative because:
1) It generally (exclusively?) relies on conditional based on other fields (handy, but not applicable) 
2) I don't want complicated logic hiding in a View.

I have tried to get hook_views_pre_render() to work - but no success. 
Again, if this was a "normal" field pulled into the view->result object, things would be easy. 
The field name is 'edit_node'. But I'm stumped on how to remove it. 
I have tried:

`$view->field['edit_node']->options['exclude'] = TRUE;`

No success

Comment: How did you add the link? Views provides a field handler out of the box which renders the link only if the user has access.

Comment: In Views you need to add `Link to edit content` as a field.